# Double-click "g" not working as expected

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender and used a boolean to cut into a shape. Now I'm trying to get rid of "n"-gons by using double-click "g" to slide "excess" edges along a face.

The trouble is that when I slide the edges:

1. the old edge remains (I made sure in the outliner that my object is the only object in the layer, i.e. I think there are no other copies -- specifically, the Outliner shows "Plane.003" and then when I click the "+" to expand, there's a "Plane.017" below it, but all my "Plane.00n" objects on other layers have "plane.00m" objects attached to them. Is this normal behavior?).
2. the edge that's slid seems to go out of the proper orientation when it's slid in one direction (but not the other).

Any ideas what might be going on? Thank you!

Comment: your explanation are very confused, for example you don't get rid of ngons with GG, you just slide your edge... please show some screenshots or share your file with only the problematic part if it's possible... https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2):

While you're waiting for an answer, you can try using Shift + V. That's an alternative hotkey to slide edges in Blender 2.79.

Comment: Many thanks, Susan.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the answer was:

1. I was in orthogonal view and the lines that I thought "remained" after the edge slide were on the back of the object, so the transform was actually working properly.
2. Also, I needed to remove doubles.

As for the edge slide going off orientation in one direction but not the other, I'm not certain but I think that may also have had to do with not removing doubles because I can't reproduce that problem now.